# Tomcat service failed to start on ubuntu

Tags: tomcat

I installed tomcat9 on my ubuntu machine. But everytime I start the service and then check the status, I get this error -

[image: screenshot of sudo systemctl status tomcat]

or if I try sudo systemctl start tomcat9, then I get this error:
[image: screenshot of sudo systemctl status tomcat9]

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
java-11-amazon-corretto        11100014   /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto
```

here is cotmcat.service file config:

```
[Unit]
 Description=Apache Tomcat 
 After=network.target
 [Service]
# Type=forking tells systemd that the process is still running even though the parent exited.
 Type=forking
 Environment=java-11-amazon-corretto=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto # Update the JAVA_HOME 
 Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
 Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
 Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
 User=tomcat
 Group=tomcat
 Restart=always
 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and this is my java version:

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.14 2022-01-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.14.9.1 (build 11.0.14+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.14.9.1 (build 11.0.14+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I think this question should move to serferfault.com

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Your question should contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and [help/on-topic] as the question (on top) seems off-topic on stackoverflow to begin with.

Comment: this is my first question and according to their rules, I can't upload the images here

Answer (score 0):

Check this below service configuration, **it is working for me**:

```
    [Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target
 
[Service]
Type=forking Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd6 Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
 
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
 
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For details, you can go [here](https://www.cloudsigma.com/installing-apache-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

```
Type=forking Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd6 Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
```